# angularJS directive with isolated scope, attribute binding doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Please see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/viro/DK5pC/3/

What I did looks right compared to the tutorials and replies I've found, so I'm sure I'm overlooking something trivial.

I'm trying to do a directive on a html element, that will create a sibling div to display a message associated with the original element.

for example, for this html :

```
<input ng-model="inp" tst-msg="message" />
```

I would create as a sibling element:

```
<div class="msg">Msg:<span ng-bind="tstMsg"></span></div>
```

I was hoping that `tstMsg` in the div's scope would be bound to `message` in the input's scope.

Here's what the directive looks like :

```
angular.module('tst', [])
 .directive('tstMsg', function(){
    var template = "<div class='msg' >Msg:<span ng-bind='tstMsg'></span></div>";

    var link = function(scope,element,attrs) {
        element.parent().append(template);
        console.log("link called");
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          tstMsg: '='
        },
        link: link
    };
});
```

Well that doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `$compile` the template you're adding to the DOM.  Angular hasn't had a chance to add it's handlers, for instance the `ng-bind` directive to that part of the dom.

So instead of just adding the element like this:

```
element.parent().append(template);
```

These steps will let Angular process your template and then add it.

```
newe = angular.element(template);
$compile(newe)(scope);
element.parent().append(newe);
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DK5pC/7/)

Comment: question: why did you have to modify the scope object to  { tstMsg: '=tstMsg' } ? I thought with just '=' it'd work.

Comment: Good catch - short answer is yes just the equal sign alone is good `{ tstMsg: '=' }`.  Background is the fiddle in your link had `tstBubble: '='` which I switched to `tstBubble: '=tstMsg'`.  Then I saw your post used `tstMsg` instead of `tstBubble` so I switched the names in the code to match your post, but using a global search and replace.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that. I thought I had renamed it to tstMsg before posting the link.